# How can I install custom fonts on Android?

Tags: fonts

I am trying to display a Powerpoint slide deck on an android tablet, but the slides contain fonts that don't exist in android.

Is there a way to install custom fonts on the tablet?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no. Some apps will let you add extra fonts to your SD card and search for then there, but that's app-specific.

If your device is rooted, you could replace the built in fonts with those of your choosing, but that's a system-wide change.

Comment: That leads to a more specific question that I'll ask separately.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/48665/13613), there are several apps which allow you to install custom fonts.  Not all devices support this without rooting, so YMMV.

[Font Installer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.font.installer) and [iFont](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kapp.ifont) seem like good options.