# Japanese keyboard/fonts on Samsung Ace

Tags: keyboard, fonts

can I add Japanese keyboard and font for e-mail input on Samsung ACE8android 2.Etc?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [How can I install custom fonts on Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/11789/16575) (plus the [list of font questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts)), and also the [questions tagged `keyboard`](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard) while waiting for an anser.