# Does Android support new fonts?

Tags: fonts

Does the Android operating system support installing **new** fonts?

I am that person who adores calligraphy and improving handwriting, and I am proud to say that my handwriting is now more beautiful than my teachers in almost every language I know! Anyway, can anyone answer that question (about Android fonts), because this will judge if I will buy a ruuning-Android tablet pc or not!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install custom fonts on Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11789/how-can-i-install-custom-fonts-on-android)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can install new fonts, but it requires root on most devices.

To install a font, you just simply need to copy the font file (.ttf format only) into /system/fonts.  There are also numerous apps available on the Play store to do this automatically for you, such as the plainly named [Font Installer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.font.installer).  Other apps also include functionality to find new fonts.

[With the right app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kapp.ifont), it is also possible to install fonts without root on the Samsung Galaxy S3, S4, Note, and Note 2.