# Installing a font in android

Tags: languages, system, fonts

I have a TTF font file which I can double click in windows and click install and that font gets installed. But in case of Android

1. Putting TTF in `/system/fonts` alone doesn't help
2. Using font changers from market (what they do is basically put the TTF file in the fonts directory renaming it to Roboto) works, but they change system wide font

What I want is, use my default font everywhere except in say an Urdu eBook which declares specific Urdu font to be used which I want to install.

More like a Windows approach to install a font, how can I do that in Android? I'm using 4.4.4

Comment: You might wish to see: [How can I install custom fonts on Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/11789/16575) – and [some more related questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts?sort=frequent).

Comment: The first link says it's not possible which I don't agree with.

Comment: What do you mean you "don't agree" with it? The fact that you **want** it to be possible doesn't mean it is.