# Add fonts to Hancom office, Samsung Galaxy Note Pro

Tags: samsung, fonts

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note Pro, which came with Hancom office.
I write many multilingual documents and the fonts that are available are just boring. I have many fonts, (.ttf and .otf) that I have downloaded but cannot use them.
Is there a way to use these fonts with Hancom's office for Android?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Always a good idea on our site: checking the related tag-wiki. Here [fonts](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/fonts/info) had pointed you to: [How can I install custom fonts on Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/11789/16575) and some more helpful posts. Good luck!

Comment: @Izzy, I have seen this question and it seems to be asking a different question. I am able to change the system font but not the fonts in Hancom Office.

Comment: Ah. Always good to point out such things. I'd recommend you [edit] your question and include that fact, before the threshold of "close as dupe" is reached (I'm retracting my vote now due to that fact).

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the generic 'how to add fonts to android' link you provide.  If you view that posting it says - no you can't do it, but your specific app might allow it.  And here the OP is asking about a specific app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Font directory is `/storage/emulated/0/.Hnc/HOffice9/Shared/Fonts`.
To add additional user fonts, put the fonts in this folder.