# Easiest way to add a font so Chrome will recognize it on a Nexus 10?

Tags: chrome-for-android, fonts

I want Chrome for Android to recognize the Verdana font on a Nexus 10.  That's it.  Currently, it only seems to recognize Arial, Open Sans, Times New Roman, and a couple of fixed width fonts.  All of these fonts are just terrible, and I'm left baffled by why Google would make such a tiny number of fonts available.

Is there a solution to this that does not involve rooting?  I've spent a few hours in the app store and looking it up online and I haven't been able to find anything.

(Ideally, I'd like to be able to also change the default fonts for Chrome for Android; but that's likely more impossible and is far less important to me.)

Comment: Have you seen our [fonts tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/fonts/info) yet, Trixie? You might wish to follow it up to [How can I install custom fonts on Android?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/11789/16575)

Answer (score 0):

Verdana is a proprietary font. Although Microsoft once released it as a part of [Core fonts for the Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_fonts_for_the_Web), they didn't allow to repackage it with other products, and then shut the whole project down.

Android has [its own Roboto font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113420/roboto-font-for-android-4).

Comment: This doesn't answer either of my questions, which remain valid because it is legal to download and use Verdana as an end-user.  Roboto is not a substitute because "Verdana" will default to Arial (or something that looks very much like Arial).

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that. I wasn't sure, if you are doing that just for yourself, or as a publicly available thing. What I would do in this case, is taking Verdana as a web font, changing the [default user agent stylesheet for Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/css/html.css) and [rebuilding it myself](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/AndroidBuildInstructions).